# Make a billing details default? Is it correct English?

Tags: sentence, syntactic-analysis

We have a situation where we are asking the user to select one billing details and make it default, from the different billing details that he has already provided to us. The billing details consider of multiple information like: Name, Address, Phone No. etc. What would be the correct sentence for this one?

"Make a billing details default?" I feel there is something wrong in this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot use "billing details" this way. The basic problem is that "a" is a singular article, and "billing details" is a plural verb, so you can't use them together.

There are a couple options for how to fix this mismatch. The easiest way would be to make "billing details" part of a singular noun phrase:

> A set of billing details

This is now singular, and can be used as you originally proposed:

> Make a set of billing details your default

A second way would be to use a plural article:

> Make these billing details your default

Or you could rephrase the sentence to avoid using any article:

> Set your default billing details

Comment: I think, "Make the selected billing details your default" should do the job for me. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

> Create a default for *billing details?*

Comment: I might prefer "Choose" over "Create" or "Make", since the data already exist, and you are simply choosing which has priority.

Comment: Sorry to co-opt your answer, but I felt it needed an explanation.

Comment: No problem. You made a useful and sensible suggestion. :-)

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that 'Billing Details' is the title of a section of a form.  In that case it is singular, despite its nominal form, because there it is a 'place' in a metaphorical sense and a not a set of objects.

However, such things always need to be it marked out from the text in a way that emphasizes that the wording is a title and not a description.

> The file was a *Moby* Dick parody.
>
> Select an item from the "Entrees" page.

So..

> Choose a "Billing Items" default.

or

> Choose a *Billing Items* default.

Answer (score 0):

By analogy with [**select a default printer**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=select+a+default+printer%2Cchoose+a+default+printer&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cselect%20a%20default%20printer%3B%2Cc0), consider simply saying:

> "[**Select**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/select) a default billing address."